# System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." clientInfo.bank_account_id было null

Tags: .net, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-core

у меня проект на ASP Net, немогу реализовать нормальную отправку с формы на сайте в бд информацию. По одному из видео смотрел изночально проект работает у самого кодера, но стоило мне сделать БД под себя и изменить код то начало быть все плохо. Я ввожу в поле bank_account_id значение (были цифры, даже буквы пытался буквы) код выдает мне clietnInfo.bank_account_id было NULL, в бд стоит тип text, и даже что он может быть NULL. Может кто-то поймет почему так?

Код Create.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ClientsBank.Pages.Clients
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        public ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
        public String errorMessage = "";
        public String successMessage = "";

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
        public void OnPost()
        {
            clientInfo.bank_account_id = Request.Form["bank_account_id"];
            clientInfo.account_money = Request.Form["account_money"];
            clientInfo.name = Request.Form["name"];
            clientInfo.email = Request.Form["email"];
            clientInfo.phone = Request.Form["phone"];
            clientInfo.address = Request.Form["address"];

            if (clientInfo.bank_account_id.Length == 0 || clientInfo.account_money.Length == 0 || 
                clientInfo.name.Length == 0 || clientInfo.email.Length == 0 ||
                clientInfo.phone.Length == 0 || clientInfo.address.Length == 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "All the fields are required";
                return;
            }
            //save new clien into database
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    String sql = "INSERT INTO clients (bank_account_id,account_money,name,email,phone,address) VALUES ('@bank_account_id','@account_money','@name','@email','@phone','@address');";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bank_account_id", clientInfo.bank_account_id);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_money", clientInfo.account_money);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", clientInfo.name);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", clientInfo.email);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", clientInfo.phone);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", clientInfo.address);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
                return;
            }

            clientInfo.bank_account_id = ""; clientInfo.account_money = ""; clientInfo.name = ""; clientInfo.email = ""; clientInfo.phone = ""; clientInfo.address = "";
            successMessage = "New Client Added SuccessFully";

            Response.Redirect("/Clients/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Код Create.cshtml:

```
@page
@model ClientsBank.Pages.Clients.CreateModel
@{
}
<br />
<h2>New Clients</h2>
@if (Model.errorMessage.Length > 0)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>@Model.errorMessage</strong>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
}
<form method="POST">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Bank Account</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="@Model.clientInfo.bank_account_id" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Money</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="@Model.clientInfo.account_money" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="@Model.clientInfo.name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="@Model.clientInfo.email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Contact</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="@Model.clientInfo.phone" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="@Model.clientInfo.address" />
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.successMessage.Length > 0)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>@Model.successMessage</strong>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            </button>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Visual Studio 2022 останавливает на:

```
if (clientInfo.bank_account_id.Length == 0 || clientInfo.account_money.Length == 0 || 
                clientInfo.name.Length == 0 || clientInfo.email.Length == 0 ||
                clientInfo.phone.Length == 0 || clientInfo.address.Length == 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "All the fields are required";
                return;
            }
```

Используется .NET 6.0, стоит из NuGet System.Data.SqlClient